# Cube inscribed into a dipyramid

Tags: mesh, polyhedra

Starting with code [nicely done at this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181991/cubes-inscribed-into-a-tetrahedron), I have been able to produce this graphic

[image: polyhedron1]

Several problems remain:

For Dipyramid, there is a superfluous line through the center of the cube. There are two ways to eliminate this. One is to remove it with this line of code

```
MeshPrimitives[
 MeshRegion[
  MeshCoordinates[T2],
  Cases[MeshCells[T2, 1], Except[Line[{1, 6}]]]
  ], 1]
```

To get this result with slightly different styling

[image: polyhedron2]

Alternatively, we could start with Octahedron which does not have the offensive center line. But `PolyhedronData` does not appear to have a simple Octahedron choice for its first argument. `Octahedron` is a `Graphics3D` object. Much changes in the original post when `PolyhedronData` is not the starting point.

In the end, the graphic (without the center line) needs to be nested itself inside an appropriately sized cube, so "cubelist" in the original code needs to produce two cubes of different sizes rather than three cubes with different rotations. To do that, I need a better understanding of parts of the code in the original post, especially what the "edgepairs" refer to, the composition of "U" and the use of `\[Xi]` dot products which I presume is for sizing inside objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the arteficial edge is that `PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "MeshRegion"]` is a tet-mesh for the solid polytope. We can apply `RegionBoundary` to obtain just its boundary surface.

Since you seem to aim at plotting duals of Platonic solids, you may exploit that the vertices of the dual are just the face centroids.

```
dualPolyhedron[M_] := RegionBoundary[ConvexHullMesh[RegionCentroid /@ MeshPrimitives[M, {2}]]];
extractEdges[M_, r_] := MeshPrimitives[M, {1}] /. Line[x___] :> Tube[x, r];

M0 = RegionBoundary[PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "MeshRegion"]];
M1 = dualPolyhedron[M0];
M2 = dualPolyhedron[M1];
M3 = dualPolyhedron[M2];

r = 0.015/2
Graphics3D[{Gray, Specularity[White, 30],
  (*extractEdges[M0,r],*)
  extractEdges[M1, r],
  extractEdges[M2, r],
  extractEdges[M3, r]
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: That should do it, once I add another cube around the outside. Still studying your code on the original, making progress understanding your wizardry. Thanks. RJB

Comment: There is something I am missing. After adding a layer and trying ALL the permutations I can only get the Octahedron on the outside of the three. The order, traveling inward from largest to smallest should be Cube,Octahedron,Cube.

Comment: I updated my post to address this.

Answer (score 2):

Get the line primitives for `Octahedron` and its dual using `PolyhedronData` properties:

```
{octahedronLines, cubeLines} = Map[PolyhedronData[#, "Lines"] &] @
   {"Octahedron", PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Dual", "Name"]}
```

A helper function that (1) scales `Lines` and (2) replaces `Line`s with `Tube`s:

```
linesToTubes[scale_ : 1, r_ : .02] := ReplaceAll[Line[x_] :> Tube[x scale, r]]
```

Scale `cubeLines` by `Sqrt[2]` and `Sqrt[2]/3` to get the edges of bounding and inscribed cuboids, respectively:

```
Graphics3D[{Gray, Specularity[White, 30], 
  linesToTubes[] @ octahedronLines, 
  linesToTubes[Sqrt[2]] @ cubeLines,
  linesToTubes[Sqrt[2]/3] @ cubeLines}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]